# Adding a custom page tab to an application page

Tags: facebook, tabs

I am trying to add a custom page tab to my application about page (or whatever this is now called). For exemple if I try to add Static FBML to my application page, I go here http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878, click on "Add to my page" on the left, and a popup appears "Add Static FBML to your Page, Select which Page you wish to add Static FBML to.".

The problem is that that popup doesn't have any of my applications. It only has the page about my blog that I am admin of (Which is not an app). I tried several applications for tabs, and none showed any application in the popup.

I was able to install page tabs before, as I actually installed the "Poll" application on one of my application pages, but it seems to no longer work.

Am I doing something wrong, or did Facebook just silently remove the ability to install page tabs on application pages? Many apps use "Static FBML" to show a landing page, does Facebook provide an alternate way to do that without installing page tabs?

Comment: There's a currently open bug report about this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/215461228517746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This still hasn't been fixed, but Adam Konrad posts a workaround in this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/240037952714577